# Can Line2D and Rectangle2D be used without generating graphics?

Tags: java

Java student here

I'm trying to create a line that moves as I move a physical accelerometer/gyro, and a method that returns TRUE when the line intersects with rectangles I've positioned in a 2D coordinate system.

Obviously Line2D and Rectangle2D are graphical classes which I've just discovered won't work unless it's set in a JFrame and painted, which I'm not looking for. So I was wondering if there were other classes that might be better suited for this. Or do I have to manually always calculate the equation of the line segment, and four sides of a rectangle segment and check for intersections that way?

Any ideas?

Comment: To find out if a line intersects a rectangle it would be easier to look if at least one of the endpoints of the line lies inside of the rectangle. No line equations involved. :-)

Comment: @Aron_dc A line segment with both endpoints outside of a rectangle can still intersect it. I'm afraid it does require more than a simple test.

Comment: @G_H Oh dang, you're correct. It was even covered in my computer graphics classes several years ago.

Comment: I've just had a look at the Javadocs for the classes and I can't see why you need to create a JFrame?

Comment: _"Obviously Line2D and Rectangle2D are graphical classes which I've just discovered won't work unless it's set in a JFrame and painted"_ what do you mean by that? There's nothing that stops you using a Rectangle2D (specifically its subclass Rectangle) without painting anything in a JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes just encapsulate shape information. You can use them perfectly fine without rendering and even in a "headless" (no rendering hardware) environment.

```
Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(1, 5, 4, 0);
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(1, 1, 2, 2);
System.out.println(line.intersects(rect));
```

This outputs "true".

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason when I had tried running this, I kept getting errors in the output (Null pointers). I'll give it another go. I appreciate it, mate.